# How can I expand a single-quoted tilde from xargs in sh?

Tags: shell, xargs

I have a list of files stored in a file, and I want to grep each of those files for a search term.

However, `xargs` forwards arguments as single quoted strings, so for all of the files prefixed with a `~`, I get a `No such file or directory` error, because the `~`'s aren't expanded.

Here's the command I'm running: `cat search-files | xargs -n 1 grep 'search-term'`

How can I get around this besides actually going into `search-files` and changing the paths myself?

Comment: *"going into `search-files` and changing the paths"* could be as simple as changing your `cat` command to a `sed` command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you're potentially exposing yourself to other problems: what if search-files contains the line `*` or `$(rm important-file)`?

Expanding @steeldriver's hint:

```bsh
sed "s,^~,$HOME," search-files | xargs -n 1 grep 'search-term'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out *a* solution, but I'm not quite sure why it works.

If you insert a `xargs -i sh -c 'echo {}'`, the tilde is expanded.

The whole command looks like:

```
cat search-files | xargs -i sh -c 'echo {}' | xargs -n 1 grep 'search-term'
```

Edit: Ok here's how this works:
`xargs` surrounds each of `[command]` and `[initial-args]` with single quotes when it goes to execute your command. So, with the original command, `grep` and `{}` were single quoted separately. However, by doing `sh -c 'echo {}'`, we force `echo` and `{}` into the same `[initial-arg]`. This allows `sh` to to tilde expansion normally. If we didn't single quote `'echo {}'`, this wouldn't work.

Comment: The shell is generally where `~` as a path element has any meaning.  The shell expands it to your home directory before sending it to any real API that uses it.

Comment: @AndyDalton What I'm really not clear on is when `xargs` quotes its arguments. Like:
This seems like it surrounds the arg with single quotes:
`echo "~" | xargs -i echo {}` gives `~`.
This seems like doesn't surround the arg with single quotes
`echo "~" | xargs -i sh -c "echo {}"` gives `/home/name`. Does `xargs` not use `sh` to invoke its specified command?

Comment: Try: `sh -c "echo ~"`.  By running it through the shell, the shell expands `~` to `/home/name` before invoking `echo`.  `echo` doesn't get `~`, it gets `/home/name`.

Comment: Ah ok I figured it out. `xargs` just surrounds each of `[command]` and `[initial-args]` with single quotes. Thanks!

Comment: @jpear1 `xargs` doesn't add any single-quotes, it just doesn't run the command through a shell (unless you explicitly tell it to with `sh -c`). You're assuming single-quotes because shell expansions (like `~`) don't take place, but the reason they don't take place is because there's no shell to expand them.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Oh interesting. That's what I thought at first but my brief search for how to call a unix program from C just gave me `popen`, which invokes the shell. Just out of curiosity, how is it possible to call a unix program without using the shell?

Comment: @jpear1 The usual low-level method is to [`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a subprocess, then use one of the [`exec()-family` system calls](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html). Note that `exec()` just takes a list of raw strings to pass as arguments -- no parsing performed. There are lots of higher-level wrappers for this (depending on your programming environment), but most just take a list of string arguments. *Some* wrappers take a string and pass it to a shell, but that's not what `xargs` uses.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Aaah ok, got it. Thanks for your explanation!